# Exception: Maximum number of items that can be serialized or deserialized in an object graph is '65536'

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, wcf, serialization, datacontractserializer

I looked at others posts, but I didn't find solution to my problem.

My service config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler,Log4net"/>
  </configSections>
  <appSettings>
    ...
  </appSettings>
  <log4net>
    ...
  </log4net>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add scheme="http" binding="wsDualHttpBinding"/>
    </protocolMapping>
    <services>
      <service name="Service1" behaviorConfiguration="Service1Behavior">
        <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" contract="IService1" bindingConfiguration="NetTcpBinding_IService1">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost"/>
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="/mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
      </service>
      <service name="Service2" behaviorConfiguration="Service2Behavior">
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="IService2" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IService2">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IService2" receiveTimeout="00:00:10"
          sendTimeout="00:00:10" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
          useDefaultWebProxy="false">
          <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:00:11" />
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
            maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
          <security mode="None" />
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
      <netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="NetTcpBinding_IService1" receiveTimeout="00:00:20"
          sendTimeout="00:00:20" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
            maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
          <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:00:11" />
          <security mode="None" />
        </binding>
      </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="Service1Behavior">
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="False"/>

          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True"/>
          <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="100"
                    maxConcurrentInstances="100"
                    maxConcurrentSessions="100" />
        </behavior>
        <behavior name="Service2Behavior">
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True"/>
          <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="100"
                    maxConcurrentInstances="100"
                    maxConcurrentSessions="100"  />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <connectionStrings>
    ...
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="Error,ActivityTracing"
        propagateActivity="true">
        <listeners>
          ...
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
  </system.diagnostics>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

My client config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        ...
    </configSections>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <netTcpBinding>
                <binding name="NetTcpBinding_IService1" closeTimeout="00:00:15"
                    openTimeout="00:00:15" receiveTimeout="00:00:40" sendTimeout="00:00:40"
                    transactionFlow="false" transferMode="Buffered" transactionProtocol="OleTransactions"
                    hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" listenBacklog="10"
                    maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647"
                    maxConnections="10" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
                    <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
                        maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
                    <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
                        enabled="false" />
                    <security mode="None">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" protectionLevel="EncryptAndSign" />
                        <message clientCredentialType="Windows" />
                    </security>
                </binding>
            </netTcpBinding>
            <wsHttpBinding>
                <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IService2" closeTimeout="00:00:15"
                    openTimeout="00:00:15" receiveTimeout="00:00:25" sendTimeout="00:00:15"
                    bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                    maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
                    messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="false">
                    <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
                        maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
                    <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:00:11" />
                    <security mode="None">
                        <transport realm="" />
                        <message clientCredentialType="Windows" negotiateServiceCredential="true" />
                    </security>
                </binding>
            </wsHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://.../Design_Time_Addresses/Service2/"
                binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IService2"
                contract="Service2Reference.IService2"
                name="WSHttpBinding_IService2"  behaviorConfiguration="serviceBehaviorConfiguration">
                <identity>
                    <dns value="localhost" />
                </identity>
            </endpoint>
            <endpoint address="net.tcp://.../Design_Time_Addresses/Service1/"
                binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="NetTcpBinding_IService1"
                contract="Service1Reference.IService1" name="NetTcpBinding_IService1"
                behaviorConfiguration="serviceBehaviorConfiguration">
                <identity>
                    <dns value="localhost" />
                </identity>
            </endpoint>
        </client>
      <behaviors>
        <endpointBehaviors>
          <behavior name="serviceBehaviorConfiguration">
            <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
          </behavior>
        </endpointBehaviors>
      </behaviors>
    </system.serviceModel>
    <userSettings>
        ...
    </userSettings>

</configuration>
```

Why I still get exception:

```
The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message: 
There was an error while trying to deserialize parameter http://tempuri.org/:GetData.
The InnerException message was 'Maximum number of items that can be serialized or deserialized in an object graph is '65536'. 
Change the object graph or increase the MaxItemsInObjectGraph quota. '.
```

Is seems to ignore `<dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>` in both `App.config` files. Why?

Comment: @Cybermaxs-Betclic No, it's not duplicate. I'm using "Add Service Reference" in Visual Studio so my config file is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem with adding behavior in C# code.

```
client.Endpoint.Behaviors.Remove(typeof(CallbackBehaviorAttribute));
client.Endpoint.Behaviors.Add(new CallbackBehaviorAttribute() { MaxItemsInObjectGraph = 2147483647 });
```

Problem probably is caused because of using `ServiceClient` constructor with `InstanceContext`, `Binding` and `EndpointAddress` so behavior from `app.config` is ignored.

Comment: Could you please explain where this code should go? Is it on instantiating the app? Or before each connection? Thanks. I don't fully understand the constructor issue you describe.

Answer (score 15):

At the client, see the 3 lines marked `****`:

```
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://.../Design_Time_Addresses/Service2/"
****        behaviorConfiguration="foo"
            binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IService2"
            contract="Service2Reference.IService2"
            name="WSHttpBinding_IService2">
            <identity>
                <dns value="localhost" />
            </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="net.tcp://.../Design_Time_Addresses/Service1/"
****        behaviorConfiguration="foo"
            binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="NetTcpBinding_IService1"
            contract="Service1Reference.IService1" name="NetTcpBinding_IService1">
            <identity>
                <dns value="localhost" />
            </identity>
        </endpoint>
    </client>
  <behaviors>
    <endpointBehaviors>
****  <behavior name="foo">
        <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
      </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
```

Comment: Yes, I tried this also. Still not working

Comment: @Saint hmm, ok; right - to be clear: which end is serializing when this breaks? client? or server?

Comment: Server part semms to be ok. Client part is broken

Comment: @Saint hmmm... that's vexing; unless I'm going crazy, the above should have fixed it

Comment: @Saint yes, that is normal

Answer (score 5):

Add to the config

```
<behaviors> 
    <endpointBehaviors> 
        <behavior name="Behaviors.EndpointBehavior"> 
            <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" /> 
        </behavior> 
    </endpointBehaviors> 
</behaviors
```

Then define your client with behavior

```
<client> 
    <endpoint address=http://localhost:9997/Services/MyService 
        behaviorConfiguration="Behaviors.EndpointBehavior" 
        binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHTTPBinding.Configuration.Client" 
        contract="IAppointments" name="Client.EndpointConfiguration" /> 
</client>
```

Or do it in code behind

```
foreach ( var operation in channelFactory.Endpoint.Contract.Operations )   
{   
    var behavior = operation.Behaviors.Find() as DataContractSerializerOperationBehavior;   
    if ( behavior != null )   
    {   
        behavior.MaxItemsInObjectGraph = 2147483647;       
    }   
}
```

(Source: http://devlicio.us/blogs/derik_whittaker/archive/2010/05/04/setting-maxitemsinobjectgraph-for-wcf-there-has-to-be-a-better-way.aspx)

I think you have to decorate the server side definition and the client endpoint as well.

Comment: Yes, I tried this also. Still not working

Comment: :( try regenerate client config after a rebuild

Comment: Ahh, and dont forget to apply this value on server side!

Comment: The code behind version worked for me; the accepted answer only works if you are using a duplex endpoint.